# Highlighting User Defined Keywords in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am searching XML files to see if there are contents which match the words inserted in these textboxes `txtComKeyword1`, `txtComKeyword2`, `txtComKeyword3` and/or `txtComKeyword4`. The function below is working, but may I know how can I highlight the keywords that user entered in the four textboxes that match that appear in my `richComResults` richtextbox?

For example, my user will fill in those four textboxes ie. txtComKeyword1, txtComKeyword2, txtComKeyword3 and txtComKeyword4. Then, my code will parse the XML file to see if the nodes contain these four keywords, if yes, the nodes' data will be output on my richComResults, I wanna highlight those four keywords (eg txtComKeyword1=hello, txtComKeyword2=bye, txtComKeyword3=morning, txtComKeyword4=night). These 4 words, if found and appear in richComResults, will be highlighted with color.

I have no clue after searching for a while, my case is much different from other questions. I am a newbie in programming, your help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

My Code:

```
private void searchComByKeywords()
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

            string docPath = fileName;

            xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {

                XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement) node;

                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;

                if (txtComKeyword1.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) || 
                    txtComKeyword2.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToString()) || 
                    txtComKeyword3.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToString()) || 
                    txtComKeyword4.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

                    richComResults.AppendText("Author: " + itemAuthor + "\nDate: " + itemDate + "\nTitle: " + itemTitle + "\nDescription: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int pointer = 0;
int index = 0;
string keyword = "txtComKeyword1";

while (true)
{
    index = richComResults.Text.IndexOf(keyword, pointer);
    //if keyword not found
    if (index == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    richComResults.Select(index, keyword.Length);
    richComResults.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(richComResults.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    pointer = index + keyword.Length;
}
```

This searches for the keyword and highlights it. Then it continues the search after the found keyword. The pointer is used to keep track of the search position in your text. The index marks the position of the found keyword.

Comment: But the keyword that I want is not exactly "txtComKeyword1". :| txtComKeyword1 is the textbox that allowing user to input a word.

Comment: Then just change one line: `string keyword = txtComKeyword1.Text`

Comment: what if it says "The name FontStyle does not exist in the current context"? :| my `using System.Windows.Forms;` is there.

Comment: You need `using System.Drawing;` in order to use `FontStyle`

Comment: Yes. I have copied the code from a working program of mine, so what I provided works. You just have to adapt to your situation. Maybe it has something to do with case-sensitivity? Try `string keyword = txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()`. If that does not work you have to debug your code line by line and verify that the values of your variables correspond to your expectation.

Comment: my txtComKeyword1 is set to `ToLower()`. So when user search for let say the word "polarbear", the real `PolarBear` will not be bold unless I search the exact word `PolarBear`. If I search `polarbear`, it doesn't bold.

Comment: So is that what you want? Maybe we should move that to the chat.

Comment: I couldn't talk in chat because I haven't met my 20 reputation point. Your answer is exactly what I want, but I just need to deal with the `ToLower()` thingy.:/ I tried `string keyword = txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()` it doesn't work.  Still trying

Comment: Now you can talk in the chat :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15154/discussion-between-shyuan-and-jan)

Answer (score 1):

Jan's answer contains great content, but I shuddered mildly at the while(true) and break aspect! Here's my tweaked (case-insensitive) version...

```
int nextHigh = RTF.Text.IndexOf(txSearch, 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
while (nextHigh >= 0)
{
    RTF.Select(nextHigh, txSearch.Length);
    RTF.SelectionColor = Color.Red;                            // Or whatever
    RTF.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold); // you like
    nextHigh = RTF.Text.IndexOf(txSearch, nextHigh + txSearch.Length, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
void ParseLine(string line)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex("([ \\t{}():;])");
        String[] tokens = r.Split(line);


        foreach (string token in tokens)
        {
            // Set the tokens default color and font.
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

            // Check whether the token is a keyword. 
            String[] keywords = { "Author", "Date", "Title", "Description", };
            for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (keywords[i] == token)
                {
                    // Apply alternative color and font to highlight keyword.
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                    break;
                }
            }
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = token;
        }
       richTextBox1.SelectedText = "\n";
    }
```

and after fill your string str with your method call my method :

```
string strRich =

            "Author : Habib\nDate : 2012-08-10 \nTitle : mytitle \nDescription : desc\n";


        Regex r = new Regex("\\n");
        String[] lines = r.Split(strRich);

        foreach (string l in lines)
        {
            ParseLine(l);
        }
```

enjoy.

Comment: it doesn't really reflect to what I need :| my user will fill in those four textboxes ie. `txtComKeyword1`, `txtComKeyword2`, `txtComKeyword3` and `txtComKeyword4`. Then, my code will parse the XML file to see if the nodes contain these four keywords, if yes, the nodes data will be output on my `richComResults`, I wanna highlight those four keywords (eg txtComKeyword1=hello, txtComKeyword2=bye, txtComKeyword3=morning, txtComKeyword4=night). These 4 words (if found and appear in richComResults) will be highlighted with color.